# Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of CMake

Tags: flutter, windows, cmake

I got this error when launching old flutter app for dekstop windows.

[image: Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of CMake]

I was to try change version on every CMakeList.txt to 2.8...3.5 on windows folder, nothing happened and I got another error. anyone can help me to fix this error :(

Comment: The phrase about version which you put into the title is just a **warning**, it doesn't prevent the project to be built. As for the following error, then: 1. It should be added to the question post in **textual** form, not as *image* (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). 2. You need provide **more details** about the "app" and  the way you are building it.

Comment: oke thanks, i'll share textual problem. I think with image it will simple to share, but apparently its not rekomendation to share error problem in stackoverflow.